# Passing and returning class object without "new" keyword

Tags: java, oop, object

I am a Java newbie, reading through some questions related to passing a class and return a class in Java OOP, but unfortunately cannot find the answer. So I bring up my questions, hope you guys feel free to share your ideas.

Let's say we have a codeblock about Composition " a case has something defined dimension in class "dimension":

```
public class Case {
private String model;
private Dimensions dimensions;

public Case(String model, Dimensions dimensions) {   // line AAA
    this.model = model;
    this.dimensions = dimensions;
}

public Dimensions getDimensions() { 
    return dimensions; //line BBB
```

**Question1**: at line AAA, we pass "Dimensions dimensions" into the constructor as a parameter, why don't use "new" keyword to instance object

**Question2**: at line BBB, we return "dimensions", why don't use "return **new** Dimensions" to return an object. In some articles, I see they use. SO which situation we should use "new", and which we should not?

Thank you.

Comment: Because we already are passing a fully constructed object or instance.

Answer (score 2):

> Question1: at line AAA, we pass "Dimensions dimensions" into the
>   constructor as a parameter, why don't use "new" keyword to instance
>   object

Typically, you would pass in an already created object like as shown :

```
String model = "myModel";
Dimensions dim = new Dimensions(); 
Case case = new Case(model, dim);
```

So now the dimensions variable of the case object would hold a reference to the dimension object passed via the constructor.

> Question2: at line BBB, we return "dimensions", why don't use "return
>   new Dimensions" to return an object. In some articles, I see they use.
>   SO which situation we should use "new", and which we should not?

The method `getDimensions()` is a getter method meaning that we want to get the value of `this` objects dimension. So returning a new dimension object doesn't make sense. To get the dimension of the `case` object created above you would use :

```
Dimensions caseDimension = case.getDimensions();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just would like to make sure I understand yours correctly, 
+ Passing something into parameter of a constructor/method: they should be reference ? like public String getMoney (String name)  <<< String name is a reference NOT a value. It's same to Dimension dimension in line AAA of my example.

 + Returning of a method: should be value; but "return dimension " is it a value or reference ?

Comment: **(a) Passing something into parameter of a constructor/method: they should be reference ?** -- No. If it's a primitive (like int, etc) then there is no concept of reference/object. **(b) public String getMoney (String name) <<< String name is a reference NOT a value** -- Correct. Here we are passing in a *String literal*. **(c) but "return dimension " is it a value or reference** -- Reference.

Answer (score 0):

The `Dimensions` instance in your example is constructed outside the `Case` class.

For example, a possible usage of the class could be:

```
Dimensions dim = new Dimensions ();
Case c = new Case ("something", dim);
```

and later

```
Dimensions d = c.getDimensions();
```

As you can see, we are passing a reference to a `Dimensions` object to the `Case` constructor. The `Case` constructor stores that reference in an instance variable (`dimensions`), and later we can call the `getDimensions()` method in order to obtain that reference.

You only use the `new` keyword when you want to construct a new object of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the answer to your sub-question:
*In some articles, I see they use.*.

Suppose you have the method in your `Case` which is purpose to change the dimensions in some way and returning it, for example 
   `public Dimensions stretch()`. 
In this case you can use 
   `return new Dimensions();`

```
public Dimensions stretch(//some arguments){
    this.dimensions = new Dimensions(//args);
    return dimensions;
}
```